# canonical divisor smooth plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given a smooth plane curve is it true that an effective canonical divisor is an hyperplane divisor?

My reasoning is the following (is it correct?):

Given a smooth plane curve of degree $d$ I want to look at $O_X(1)$ since its sections are the hyperplane divisors. We have $deg(O_X(1))=d$ by bezout, while the canonical sheaf $\omega_X$ has degree $2g-2$, so to be a canonical divisor we must have $2g-2=d$, or $d(d-3)=d$, which has solution for $d=0,4$, hence the only curve which may satisfy the requirement is a curve of degree 4 and how was shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391419/plane-curve-of-degree-4/%22here%22) it actually satisfies the requirement.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Didn't you show that your question can have an affirmative answer only if $d=4$ as opposed to the first sentence above? If $d=4$, what you say is correct of course.

Comment: I am not sure my reasoning is correct, so I wanted to know if what I said is correct. If it is not I wanted to know the correct answer to my first question. What makes it unclear?

Comment: Hyperplane divisors are canonical divisors in your situation only when degree is 4. So, the question as you stated is not true for other degrees.

Comment: Thanks. My confusion came from this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062766/elementary-reason-why-an-effective-canonical-divisor-is-a-hyperplane-section where the author says that every canonical divisor is an hyperplane section and it was not clear if he just intended for quartic or in general.

Comment: In that question, the OP is dealing only with quartic curves.

Comment: I have edited my previous comment. It was not so clear to me from his formulation and the answer he recieved since the answer started in the general setting of a degree d plane curve.I know it is straightforward, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a crucial thing in the general theory.